# Why does "for-each select" funtion in xslt not printing elements name and tags?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following, source xml file, xslt code and output xml

The issue is that I need to loop through the node JLine
using the:

```
xsl:for-each select="JLine"
```

Which is the correct output but with missing tags. 
I need to implement the loop because I will be using the if condition to process the node and eliminate some unwanted elements.

XML input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <JLine sequence="1">
            <Amount currencyID="USD">-700.000</Amount>
            <FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">-700.000</FunctionalAmount>
            <ReportingCurrencyAmount currencyID="USD">-700.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
            <GLAccount>
                <GLNominalAccount>S1010053</GLNominalAccount>
                <AccountingChartReference>
                    <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
                </AccountingChartReference>
            </GLAccount>
            <DimensionCodes>
                <DimensionCode sequence="1" listID="VAT">KTS08010</DimensionCode>
                <DimensionCode sequence="2" listID="FILE">KF86155281</DimensionCode>
            </DimensionCodes>
        </JLine>
                    <JLine sequence="2">
            <Amount currencyID="USD">-700.000</Amount>
            <FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">50.000</FunctionalAmount>
            <ReportingCurrencyAmount currencyID="USD">400.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
            <GLAccount>
                <GLNominalAccount>S1010053</GLNominalAccount>
                <AccountingChartReference>
                    <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
                </AccountingChartReference>
            </GLAccount>
            <DimensionCodes>
                <DimensionCode sequence="1" listID="VAT">mKTS08010</DimensionCode>
                <DimensionCode sequence="2" listID="FILE">eKF86155281</DimensionCode>
            </DimensionCodes>
        </JLine>
```

xlt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="JLine"> 
     <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="DimensionCodes/DimensionCode" /> 
    <xsl:if test="$var:v1">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="." />

    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

XML output result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <JLine sequence="1">
            <Amount currencyID="USD">-700.000</Amount>
            <FunctionalAmount currencyID="USD">-700.000</FunctionalAmount>
            <ReportingCurrencyAmount currencyID="USD">-700.000</ReportingCurrencyAmount>
            <GLAccount>
                <GLNominalAccount>S1010053</GLNominalAccount>
                <AccountingChartReference>
                    <ID accountingEntity="T00">T00</ID>
                </AccountingChartReference>
            </GLAccount>
            <DimensionCodes>
                <DimensionCode sequence="1" listID="VAT">KTS08010</DimensionCode>
                <DimensionCode sequence="2" listID="FILE">KF86155281</DimensionCode>
            </DimensionCodes>
        </JLine>
```

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you (a) formatted your code properly and (b) included the expected result (as code). Minimizing the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem would also be welcome.

Comment: @michael.hor257k  I did every thing to upload the example code.. but the formating is not working.. Code upload would have been a fine features

Answer (score 0):

You have an `xsl:for-each` instruction outside of any template. This is not allowed and will cause an error (and not the result you report).

I am guessing (!) you want to replace this part:

```
<xsl:for-each select="JLine"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    <Amount>
        <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
    </Amount>
</xsl:for-each>
```

with:

```
<xsl:template match="JLine">
    <Amount>
        <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
    </Amount>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Dear mich I need to loop through the JLine node and performe the "if " function.. your answer is not using the   for-each condition

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what you mean. `xsl:for-each` is not a condition.

Comment: Sorry.. I need to do xsl:for-each loop on the Node JLine. If DimensionCodes/DimensionCode is not null the Jline Node will be mapped .. If not the JLine node will be ignored

Comment: "*I need to do xsl:for-each loop on the Node JLine*" I don't see why, but if you do, you must do so inside a template.  I am unable to help you further, because you have not taken my advice how to make your question more clear. On the contrary, you have added another piece of code that has nothing to do with your question and only serves to confuse.